# Получить доступ к переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Запутался что то,как доступ получить к `eda` в этом моменте  `$("#test").text("="+eda);`

```
 var eda="";
$(document).on('tap', '#linkbreakfast', function() { eda="breakfast";});
$(document).on('tap', '#linkdinner', function() { eda="dinner";});

$("#test").text("="+eda);
```

Comment: дай угадаю, по клику текст в `$("#test")` должен был обновляться, а он не обновляется? :)

Comment: у тебя в событии отработает присвоение значения переменной, но  `text("="+eda);` уже была выполнена к этому времени

Answer (score 1):

```
var eda="";
$(document).on('tap', '#linkbreakfast', function() { SetEda("breakfast");});
$(document).on('tap', '#linkdinner', function() { SetEda("dinner");});

function SetEda(value) {
  eda = value;
  $("#test").text("="+eda);
}
```

Comment: в чем смысл тогда переменной `eda`?

Comment: @Invision, в том, что она может использоваться где-то дальше в коде

Comment: гадание на кофейной гуще

Comment: А как потом в другом месте получить? var `eda=SetEda();`?

Comment: @zkolya - Получить что? Там где видна переменная `eda`, Вы можете просто ее использовать.